# What's the most adequate test/tests for this study?

Tags: biostatistics, ecology, diversity

I'm a PhD student (Biodiversity and Animal Ecology). I am preparing a scientific article to submit and I need help in statistical analysis of my data. In this message I will try to provide as much as possible details of my study.

- I selected three olive orchards situated in a 10 x 10 km area and differing in their level of agricultural intensification (low, medium, and high) applying an index which was already used in several similar studies.
- Surveys were conducted from March 2014 to February 2015 (12 consecutive months) with a frequency of two counts per month (n = 24 visits). In each visit, the three orchards were visited.
- For gathering data on bird species diversity, I used a method to estimate species richness (number of species) regardless of species abundances. At the end i counted 23 bird species in all the olive orchards.
- Birds were classified into four feeding guilds: carnivore, omnivore, insectivore, and granivore.
- Birds were also classfied into four phenological categories: partial migrant, resident breeder, summer migrant, and winter migrant.
- Now, my final goal is to test if agricultural intensification has an effect on these birds or not. What test/tests should I use?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "has an effect on these birds or not"?  You mean how does it affect each classifaction? Or species richness?

Comment: Exactly, how does it affect species richness and the two classifications.

Comment: Your sampling design is very complicated, an example of the data would be useful to understand how your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you don't have enough replicates since you only have 3 trees, but you have temporal replicates and your response variable is richness, which likely follows a non-Gaussian distribution. If I get it right, you should use a GLMM with richness as predicted by agricultural intensification as fixed factor and month of sampling as random factor. For the other traits, do you have richness of carnivores, omnivores etc? If so, the rationale is similar.